# Django model.Model.'instance' raises AttributeError

Tags: python, django, model

I am making a website with a strava app using django. However, while trying to store a refresh token (code below) the programm runs into a AttributeError.

```
u.refresh_token = str(answer['refresh_token'])
```

u is an instance of the User class:

```
class User(models.Model):
   username = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
   password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   strava_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   refresh_token = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   cookie = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='None')
```

Error:

```
AttributeError 'dict' object has no attribute 'refresh_token'
```

I can see why the code does this, because, when looking a the local variables, it shows that u does in fact have the attribute refresh_token.

```
u{'cookie': 'oP2L2ZDziOl7obaaYXmhFcOfRdXmOXurdqURXhX4JsWnPE1FQAIbGoEwpbcXax3h','password': 'W00lly!',

'refresh_token': '', 'strava_id': '', 'username': 'jeroenkodde'}
```

I tested if it maybe was the anwer dict, but that did not cause the issue. Just for clarity I included the answer dictionary as well:

```
answer  
{'access_token': '1346cc9606e18693e28c8547100ab936a14973ed',
 'athlete': {'badge_type_id': 0,
             'city': '',
             'country': None,
             'created_at': '2018-06-02T15:23:17Z',
             'firstname': 'Jeroen',
             'follower': None,
             'friend': None,
             'id': 31434041,
             'lastname': 'Kodde',
             'premium': False,
             'profile': 'avatar/athlete/large.png',
             'profile_medium': 'avatar/athlete/medium.png',
             'resource_state': 2,
             'sex': 'M',
             'state': '',
             'summit': False,
             'updated_at': '2020-07-25T13:14:48Z',
             'username': None},
 'expires_at': 1596300110,
 'expires_in': 20754,
 'refresh_token': '6924c5675d15ca6faae478dc3bd9791e78b7227c',
 'token_type': 'Bearer'}
```

Also, when testing this in the shell it worked.
Can somebody tell me what is wrong with the code.

Comment: Try print(answer) and check which attributes it has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `u` is a dictionary, you should use:

```
u['refresh_token'] = str(answer['refresh_token'])
```

The way you are trying to access `u` should be done only if `u` is a class.

Comment: I edited my question. This case is weird because it is in fact a class object.

Comment: What is inside the variable `answer`?

Comment: Also, how do you initialize the variable `u`?

Comment: This solution is in fact right. I mistook the variable ```u``` for an instance of the User class, while it was actually a dictionary object. I changed the way I initialized ```u``` and now it works.